# Android Custom EditText is resized by keyboard open and close

Tags: android, android-edittext

i implemented a custom background for my EditText fields because i think the defaults for the EditTexts are too tall & have too much padding.  anyway, the new EditText drawable backgrounds are displaying fine, BUT the fields shrink slightly when i open the keyboard and expand to their original (custom) size when i close the keyboard.  this behavior must be overridable in some way that i just haven't stumbled across.  can anyone help, please?  I've read the IMEOptions article at the dev android site and nothing there really jumps out at me at as a possible solution to this problem.  thanks!

here is my EditText - each EditText is in its own layout because i needed to add padding BETWEEN the fields:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingBottom="5dip" android:paddingLeft="3dip"  android:paddingRight="3dip">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/join_firstName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/joinedittextselector" android:padding="5dip" />  <!-- android:layout_weight="1" -->
    </LinearLayout>
```

here is my selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/join_field_bg_default" />
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/join_field_bg_default" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/join_field_bg_default" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/join_field_bg_selected" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/join_field_bg_default" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/join_field_bg_selected" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/join_field_bg_default" />
```

i've tried adjustResize and adjustPan for the android:windowSoftInputMode setting of the activity that the EditText is used in and neither have worked. thanks again for any advice on this!

Comment: How about attaching a screen grab to show the problem?

Comment: "each EditText is in its own layout because i needed to add padding BETWEEN the fields" -- use `android:layout_margin*` for that.

Comment: that sure makes a lot more sense.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to provide images for the various states defining them in an xml resource. People do this a lot for buttons.